# Is it possible to remove floating point errors without resorting to arbitrary-precision datatypes?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, precision

I was wondering whether, under specific conditions, it is possible to remove floating point errors without resorting to arbitrary-precision datatypes.

The problem is the usual one. The language is Ruby, but it holds in any language:

```
f = 1829.82
=> 1829.82

f / 12.0
=> 152.485

(f / 12.0).round(2)
=> 152.48
```

Why not 152.49? Because due to the finite precision of floating points:

```
format("%18.14f", f)
=> "1829.81999999999994"

format("%18.14f", f / 12.0)
=> "152.48499999999999"
```

So the rounding is correct. Now my question is: is there a way to get the answer I want anyway, given the following circumstances: there are strong limits on the (number of) operations performed using float, the precision needed is limited to two decimal places (max 8 digits in total) and a small amount of remaining 'wrongly' rounded answers is acceptable?

The situation is such that users may enter valid Ruby strings like:

```
"foo / 12.0"
```

where foo is a number provided in the context in which the string is executed, but where '12.0' is something the user enters. Imagine a spreadsheet with some free formula fields. The strings are simply evaluated as Ruby, so 12.0 becomes a Float. I could use the ruby_parser + ruby2ruby gems to build a parse tree, mangle the datatype to Bignum, Rational, something from the Flt library, decimal floating point representations or what-have-you, but that is tricky, as the actual strings can become somewhat more complex, so I prefer not to go this way. I will go that way if nothing else is possible, but this question is specifically here to see if I can avoid that path. As such, the datatype of the 12.0 is strictly Float and the outcome is strictly Float and the only thing I can do is interpret the final answer of the snippet and attempt to 'correct' it, if it rounds the 'wrong' way.

The only calculations the users do involve numbers with a precision of two decimal digits (and at most 8 digits in total). With 'simple' I mean that the floating point errors do not get a chance to accumulate: I may add two of these numbers and divide one by an integer, but then the calculation is done, the result is rounded and stored and any subsequent calculation is based on that rounded number. Usually only one floating point error will be involved, but I think the problem does not significantly alter if two can accumulate, though the residual error rate may be larger by definition.

What may first come to mind is first rounding to 3 decimal digits, then to 2. However, that doesn't work. That would lead to

```
152.48499999999999 => 152.485 => 152.49
```

but also

```
152.4846 => 152.485 => 152.49
```

which is not what you want.

What next came to my mind is adding the smallest possible increment (which, as people have pointed out, depends on the floating point value under consideration) to a float *if* that nudges it over the .5 border. I'm mainly wondering how often that could result in a 'false positive': a number to which the smallest increment is added, even though the fact that it was just below the .5 border was not due to a floating point error, but because it was simply the result of the calculation?

A second option is: just *always* add the smallest increment to numbers, as the .5 region is the only one where it matters anyway.

Edit: 
I just rewrote the question to incorporate part of my answers in comments, as cdiggins suggested. I awarded the bounty to Ira Baxter for his active participation in the discussion, though I'm not yet convinced he is right: Mark Ransom and Emilio M Bumachar seem to support my idea that a correction is possible that will, in practice, in possibly a relatively large majority of cases, produce the 'correct' result.

I still have to perform the experiment to see how often the result would be correct and I fully intend to, but the time I can spend on this is somewhat limited, so I haven't gotten round to it yet. The experiment is not trivial.

Comment: Most computer languages stop at about 16 _significant_ digits because they, _and the underlying hardware_, are based on IEEE 754.  Spreadsheets use "decimal" arithmetic with more precision than that.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you want are fixed-precision decimal numbers.  A good library implementing these is going to be more reliable than hacking something together yourself.

For Ruby, check out the [Flt library](http://flt.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Changing the datatype of the numbers is going to be pretty hard, because they are coming from a piece of Ruby being instance_evalled and I don't have control over what is entered. I could rewrite the expressions using the RubyParser and Ruby2Ruby gems, but I have the feeling there may be a simpler solution for this specific situation. I would use infinite precision, whether Flt or stdlib BigDecimal, if that were easy :)

Comment: @Confusion: If you are going to insist you can't change anything, I don't see how you are going to get a fix.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: certainly not if I wanted a general solution for floating point errors. However, I'm only looking for a solution *for  this specific situation*: requiring only a precision far above the size of the floating point error, only requiring it for a single sum/division and accepting a small amount of errors (as long as it is much smaller than what I currently have due to the 'regular' floating point error. The question is mainly whether the solution I sketch misses something obvious, but I guess I will just implement it and simulate the behavior.

Comment: "Changing the datatype of the numbers is going to be pretty hard ... ". If it is a requirement on the solution: that the data-types can't be changed then please state so in the problem. You sound on the fence here.

Comment: Whether you used "fixed precision" or "floating precision" is irrelevant I believe. What is key is the "decimal representation" of the numbers.

Comment: @cdiggins: Yes, which is why my answer specifically says "fixed-point _decimal_ numbers" and links to a Ruby library providing them.

Comment: I've modified the question to reflect why it is somewhat difficult to change the datatype. I figured my mention of infinite precision arithmetic (now adjusted to 'arbitrary-precision'), which I thought always uses a decimal representation, would make clear that I understood that would be a solution, but that I was looking for another one.

Answer (score 5):

"it is possible to remove floating point errors without resorting to infinite precision datatypes."?

No. Floating point errors are your computer's only mistakes involving number crunching. If you remove all errors, by definition your precision is infinite.

That sounded pedantic, which was not my intention. I'm trying to point out that there is a big conceptual problem underneath your apparently technical issue. **You can't correctly round incorrect numbers based on what their correct values would be, unless you know their correct values** (i.e. infinite precision values, or other form of carrying that information).

Your idea of adding a small number may work out statistically, but only statistically. I suggest you write a script to test a massive number of cases with random numbers of no more than two decimal places. (The script would need to also do the math with infinite precision, in order to know the right answer to compare) That way, you can measure corrections and false positives.

Answer (score 3):

If you are can control the amount of arithmetic (especially multiplies and divides), you can try simply scaling all your floating point values by some power *scale* of ten (say scale=4). 
You'll have to change the code do input, output, and multiplies and divides.

Then scale=2 decimal fractions such as 5.10 are stored exactly as 510.  Inputs need to be entered accurately; e.g., read in the string mmm.nnnn, move the decimal place *scale* locations in the string (e.g., for scale=2 ==> mmmnn.nn and then convert the string to float).  Addition/Subtraction of such fractional numbers is exact and doesn't need any code changes.   Multiplication and division loses some "decimal" precision and needs to be scaled; code that said  x*y needs to be changed to x*y/scale; x/y needs to be changed to x*scale/y.   You'll can round the string at the scale point and then output it.

This answer is the cheesy version of using a real decimal arithmetic package, mentioned by another poster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the calculations themselves, although their nature is such that they are limited in complexity, as described in the question and comments. Imagine a spreadsheet where a user can freely enter formulas, using some numbers that have been made available symbolically, but where I can only manipulate the end result. I don't want users to have to enter foo / BigDecimal.new("12.0") when they want to divide the available number indicated by 'foo' by 12 and obtain an exact answer. Nevertheless, they need an exact answer, within the limits described.

Comment: I would suggest you rewrite your question then Confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest increment that you mention is typically called epsilon. This is the smallest value that can be added to 1.0 to make a noticeable change. If you want to add it to other numbers you must scale it first: `x = x + (x * epsilon)`.

There's another [definition of epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) which is the largest rounding error of a floating point number. This definition should be half of the first one.

In theory adding an epsilon value before rounding will produce as many errors as it corrects. In practice this won't be the case, since numbers that are close to an even decimal number are much more likely to be encountered than random chance would suggest.

Comment: How do you mean that, "numbers that are close to an even decimal number are much more likely to be encountered than random chance would suggest"? Random chance is, by definition, random chance. For the likelihood of a number to differ from random chance you need to imply anything about the events that produce the numbers. But you don't mention any implications...

Answer (score 2):

I notice that in a comment to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359116/is-it-possible-to-remove-floating-point-errors-without-resorting-to-infinite-prec/6359274#6359274) it was argued that changing datatype was hard. Nonetheless I'm going to answer the question as asked:

> I was wondering whether, under
>   specific conditions, it is possible to
>   remove floating point errors without
>   resorting to infinite precision
>   datatypes.

In order to achieve exact results you will need to use [decimal floating point representations](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) of the numbers and the appropriate math routines. Note that fixed-point math libraries can still result in binary floating point errors, if they use binary representations of the numbers.

Comment: Even full decimal won't save him.  You can't represent 1/3 in decimal, without an infinite (literally) number of digits.  What you can do is to ensure that numbers going in and out in finite precision are preserved exactly (most binary/IEEE FP I/O routines go through great lengths to ensure that; going decimal makes the I/O part easy).

Comment: ... Now, if he switches to using *rationals* (pairs of arbitrary precision numbers), then he can do "exact" arithmetic; 1/3 is represented as the rational (ratio) (1,3).  And you can generate arbitrarily corrrect output results from that, because rounding is just more of same kind of arithmetic.

Comment: @Ira: And what is sqrt(2) in rationals?

Comment: @chiccodoro: Then, agreed, even rationals won't save him.  However, OP said "I'm only looking for a solution for this specific situation: requiring only a precision far above the size of the floating point error, only requiring it for a single sum/division", which rationals will handle.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, I would say that it's impossible to get the right answer all the time. As you discovered yourself, rounding twice is not the answer. Instead, try to keep the highest precision as long as possible.

However, you do have a full arsenal of function to your disposal. You can round up, round down, round to zero, round to infinity, so if you know what your algorithm is doing, you can use the appropriate function.

I would say that adding a "small" value, or "epsilon" as it's commonly called, is a feasible way. Just keep in mind that if the original value is *negative*, you would have to *substract* it rather than adding it. Also, note that if you are dealing with the full range of floating-point values, epsilon might depend on the value.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot prevent accumulation of floating-point errors because the machine arithmetic always rounds operation results to fit into the given number of bits. In addition to that, take into account that the results of many operations require an infinite number of bits to be represented exactly (e.g. 2/10=0.2 ; but it requires an *infinite* number of bits to represent exactly in base 2, which is what computers work with).

Comment: Floating point errors won't accumulate if you do not perform multiple arithmetical operations, which does not happen here. That is one of the reasons leading me to think there may be a solution that doesn't require infinite precision. Concerning the latter part of your comment: infinite precision datatypes do not require an infinite number of bits.

Comment: The term "infinite" precision is a misnomer.  It should really be "arbitrary precision".   And as I explained in another comment, 1/3 cannot be represented directly abitrary precision arithmetic (whether you choose base 2 or base 10).

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I adjusted my terminology accordingly. I've never encountered a problem with the finite precision of arbitrary-precision datatypes, so I wasn't aware of that anymore. I think I would need to do a thorough experiment to find out whether moving to arbitrary-precision would actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this unfortunately isnt your answer, but it might get you started.

Object:

```
class Object
  # Return only the methods not present on basic objects
  def local_methods
    (self.methods - Object.new.methods).sort
  end
end
```

callbacks Module:

```
module Hooker
  module ClassMethods
  private
    def following(*syms, &block)
      syms.each do |sym| # For each symbol
        str_id = "__#{sym}__hooked__"
        unless private_instance_methods.include?(str_id)
          alias_method str_id, sym    # Backup original method
          private str_id         # Make backup private
          define_method sym do |*args|  # Replace method
            ret = __send__ str_id, *args # Invoke backup
            rval=block.call(self,       # Invoke hook
             :method => sym, 
             :args => args,
             :return => ret
            )
            if not rval.nil?
              ret=rval[:ret]
            end
            ret # Forward return value of method
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def Hooker.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

And changes to Float to actually do the work:

```
if 0.1**2 != 0.01 # patch Float so it works by default
  class Float
    include Hooker
    0.1.local_methods.each do |op|
      if op != :round
        following op do |receiver, args|
          if args[:return].is_a? Float
            ret=args[:return].round Float::DIG
            ret=Hash[:ret => ret]
          end
          ret
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:** *somewhat* better is using Rational. The nmethods overriding still isnt always on (see problems, after the code):

```
  class Float
    include Hooker
    0.1.local_methods.each do |op|
      if op != :round
        following op do |receiver, args|
          if args[:return].is_a? Float
            argsin=[]
            args[:args].each do |c|
              argsin=c.rationalize
            end
            rval=receiver.rationalize.send(
                args[:method], 
                argsin
               )
            ret=Hash[:ret => rval.to_f]
          end
          ret
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Problems**: Not all method overrides are working, at least in 1.9.3p0:

```
pry(main)> 6543.21 % 137.24
=> 92.93
[... but ...]
pry(main)> 19.5.send(:-.to_sym, 16.8)
=> 2.7
pry(main)> 19.5 - 16.8
=> 2.6999999999999993
```